# Rails: get count of association through join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an entity called "**Fact**" this entity has a relationship with another entity called "**User**", this relationship is called "**Feedback**" that has 3 fields **[user_id, fact_id, score]** every time a person gives a feedback he gets who did the feedback (**user_id**) to what fact was made (**fact_id**) and what was qualified (**0,1,2**).
Well, now I want to get the list of facts with their qualifications counted, example:

```
fact : {id: 3, name: "some name", number_of_zero: 7, number_of_one: 3, number_of_two: 3}
```

where number_of is the count of the times it was qualified.

**Database Schema:**

```
  create_table "facts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "last_name"
  end

create_table "feedbacks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "score"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "fact_id"
    t.index ["fact_id"], name: "index_feedbacks_on_fact_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_feedbacks_on_user_id"
  end
```

**Relations:**

```
class Feedback < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :fact
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Fact.
  group(:id, :name).
  select(:id, name).
  left_joins(:feedbacks).
  select("COUNT(feedbacks.id) FILTER (WHERE score = 0) AS number_of_zero").
  select("COUNT(feedbacks.id) FILTER (WHERE score = 1) AS number_of_one").
  select("COUNT(feedbacks.id) FILTER (WHERE score = 2) AS number_of_two")
```

You need to `left_joins` so that facts with 0 feedback are also returned (with 0 for each count column).

As stated by Rohan, you need to add `has_many :feedbacks` in `fact.rb`

There are more complicated solutions that adapt to any number of possible scores, but in this case that would be overzealous.

*Edit: For SQLite* (I think it supports correlated subqueries ...)

```
Fact.
  select(:id, name).
  select("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedbacks WHERE score = 0 AND fact_id = facts.id) AS number_of_zero").
  select("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedbacks WHERE score = 1 AND fact_id = facts.id) AS number_of_one").
  select("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedbacks WHERE score = 2 AND fact_id = facts.id) AS number_of_two")
```

Comment: Hello, i add has_many :feedbacks but now i get this:
`SQLite3::SQLException: near "(": syntax error: SELECT "facts"."id", "facts"."title", COUNT(feedbacks.id) FILTER (WHERE score = 0) AS number_of_zero, COUNT(feedbacks.id) FILTER (WHERE score = 1) AS number_of_one, COUNT(feedbacks.id) FILTER (WHERE score = 2) AS number_of_two FROM "facts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "feedbacks" ON "feedbacks"."fact_id" = "facts"."id" GROUP BY "facts"."id", "facts"."title"`

Comment: The question has the tag `postgresql` so the answer was given for that flavor. sqlite doesn't support `FILTER`. Updating the query for sqlite... You can also consider using postgres instead, it's much more flexible ;)

Comment: one question more, i have a picture with paperclip now i get all perfect but the picture dont get the real url if not the default url, you have some idea what happend

Answer (score 1):

```
Model:
class Feedback < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :fact
end
class Fact < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :feedbacks
end
 fact = Fact.all
  array = []
 fact.each do |each_fact|
    arr = {}
    each_fact.feedbacks do |each_feedback|
       arr["id"] = each_feed_back.id
       arr["name"] = each_feedback.name
       arr["no_of_zero"] = each_feedback.score 
       array << arr
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description provided in the post it seems like you want the fact details along with score for each uniq fact.

Something as mentioned below could help you achieve:

```
Fact.joins(:feedbacks).select("facts.id, facts.title,CASE when feedbacks.score is 0 
then count(feedbacks.score) as score_0 end,
CASE when feedbacks.score is 1 then count(feedbacks.score) as score_1 end,
CASE when feedbacks.score is 2 then count(feedbacks.score) as score_2 end")
.group("feedbacks.score")
```

Above query is joining feedbacks with fact and then grouping the score values since there would only three values ie 0,1,2 (as mentioned in the post).

Comment: i get this: 
**Can't join 'Fact' to association named 'feedbacks'; perhaps you misspelled it? **
i think that is because of the relation have ** Feedback ** and not Facts, i dont know!

Comment: since a fact can have many feedbacks thus there has to be relation defined has_many :feedbacks in fact.rb

Comment: you're right, but now i get this:
`SQLite3::SQLException: near "as": syntax error: SELECT facts.id, facts.title,CASE when feedbacks.score is 0 then count(feedbacks.score) as score_0 end, CASE when feedbacks.score is 1 then count(feedbacks.score) as score_1 end, CASE when feedbacks.score is 2 then count(feedbacks.score) as score_2 end FROM "facts" INNER JOIN "feedbacks" ON "feedbacks"."fact_id" = "facts"."id" GROUP BY feedbacks.score`